# Why am I getting deprecation error on Button?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-8

[image]

So the IntelliJ is saying that `javafx.scene.control.Button` is deprecated and I can't figure out why: there are no annotations or javadocs with any kind of deprecation in the class.

And also, if `javafx.scene.control.Button` is deprecated - what am I supposed to use to create a simple button instead?

Comment: That is indeed very weird since I don't see it on this list: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Have you tried restarting IntelliJ? It's definitely not deprecated in JDK 1.8.

Comment: The link to a duplicate worked. I guess i triggered annotation inside of IDE by hand?